# C# dependency injection transient scope with static class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, static-methods

C# question here. If I create a function app that injects a service in the startup.

```cs
services.AddTransient<IMyCoolService, MyCoolService>();
```

If there is a static class inside of `MyCoolService`, will that static get created every time this service is injected?

Edit: I'm aware static class cannot be created, but what I'm asking is, since the service is transient, and gets created each time, does that mean that the static class within it, is different each time as well?

Thanks

Comment: a static class cant be instantiated

Comment: You might want to refresh yourself on what `static` means for a class or its properties.

Comment: why don't you write an integration test, and find out? It is great practice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, though the service is created several times, each of these instances uses the "same" static members of the static class.

A static class cannot be instantiated. If there is a static field that is used by the service, its content will be the same for all the instances of the service.

If you want to create an instance of the static class for each service instance, you have to remove the static keyword from the class and the members and register it as transient also.